# Transformer Pads not specified

Tags: pcb-design, transformer, power-electronics, symbol, footprint

[FCT1-50M22SLD](https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/fe569a42-533f-4322-ab3b-764883f54979/fct1xxm22sl.pdf)
Pads 3 and 8 are not specified, or am I incorrect?

How would you link the footprint to the symbol, since no models are available for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are specified. All your pads are identical. The dimensions of each pad are 1.27mm x 1.55mm. The reason every pad's dimensions aren't specified is would make drawing super messy. BTW, pins 3 and 8 are purely mechanical and don't have electrical connections. But they should still have pads for mechanical integrity.

Comment: I meant their connections are not specified. Thanks!

Comment: Because they don't exist. Some datasheets spec. unused pins as "NC" or "N/C" to indicate no connection. Coilcraft should take notes from the IC engineers.